# coordinate points after rotation of axis

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

Can you please look at this example, I have attached a very roughly drawn figure. According to the coordinate system shown in BLUE, I have two points $A(0,0)$ and $B(-5,-5)$. These two points have a distance of $7.071$ units between them and make an angle of $45^{\circ}$. Now if I rotate the axis by $45^{\circ}$ (shown in red), it will be like these two points $A$ and $B$ both are on the $x$-axis with a distance of $7.071$ units. Because of rotating the axis at exactly the same angle which these points make, so point $B$ should have the coordinates of $(-7.071,0)$, but using the rotation of axis formula, the new coordinates are given as $(-6.8819, 1.6279)$. Can you please tell me what is the reason?

My objective was to rotate the axis in such a way that both of these points come on the same axis, which will make point $A$ as $(0,0)$ as it was, and point $B$ as $(-a,0)$.

Comment: What did you use as the "rotation of axis" formula? Remember, rotating your coordinate axes is the same thing as rotating the points the opposite direction.

Comment: Here the formulas can be found, the general form of the formula is given in the "Derivation" section. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes

Comment: I made a very stupid mistake, I was solving the angles in MATLAB where the answers were in Radians not in Degrees. I just realized it. Thanks a lot for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the result should be as expected with  rotation of axis formula when $\theta = 45^\circ$:

\begin{align}x=x^\prime \cos \theta−y^\prime \sin \theta \to (x'-y')\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=-5\\y=x^\prime \sin \theta+y^\prime \cos \theta\to (x'+y')\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=-5\\(x'-y')=-5\sqrt 2
,(x'+y')=-5\sqrt 2\end{align}
$x'=-5\sqrt 2, y'=0 \to  B  (-5\sqrt2,0)$

Comment: Thank you very much.